# Error Handling in AWS API Gateway and Lambda always return 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I use serverless to implement Lambda and Api gateway. 
When I implement Error Handling, below code always get 502 bad gateway.

handler.js

```
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "status": "error",
        "message": "Missing Params"
      })
    };
    callback(response);
};
```

CloudWatch do log error.

```
{
    "errorMessage": "[object Object]"
}
```

I code this way by following the method "Custom error object serialization" in below AWS blog.
[Ref](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I change callback first parms to null and work fine. [Ref](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2174)

```
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "status": "error",
        "message": "Missing Params"
      })
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pattern in Node.js and its called ***Error-First Callbacks***.

Basically, **if you pass a first argument into your callback, it will be considered and handled as an Error.**

As you mentioned, once you put a `callback(null, response);`, it all worked as expected, since the first argument is null.